# How to skip validates_presence_of email in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I am using Devise in my Rails aplication. I succesfully changed email to username to log in. I don't want the email to be necessary when a new user is created.

Does anyone have any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in "[How To: Allow users to sign in with something other than their email address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address)".

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your configuration in devise.rb from email to username.
     config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]

Comment: I have already did that, the thing is that I dont want the email to be necessary when a new user is created, I want the email to be optional